# Opening Excel through C# then allowing the user to close Excel manually

Tags: c#, excel

After my program creates an Excel file, I let the user see that file.

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlApp.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlsx.saveLocation + "\\" + xlsx.fileName,
    0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
    true, false, 0, true, false, false);
```

Whenever I close the Excel window, the process (EXCEL.EXE) remains (I'm hitting the red X in the top right). Am I missing a setting or something? I want the Excel window to be independent of the C# program, so that if I end the latter the former will still be visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want true independence, then you should use `Process.Start` to start Excel.

The simplest version you'd need would be:

```
Process.Start(Path.Combine(xlsx.saveLocation, xlsx.fileName));
```

though I'd recommend using the proper `Path` methods for combining the directory and filename into a complete path. [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx)

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx)

If your path or filename has spaces then you need to wrap the whole thing in quotes:

```
var arguments = new StringBuilder("\"");
arguments.Append(Path.Combine(xlsx.saveLocation, xlsx.fileName));
arguments.Append("\"");
Process.Start(arguments.ToString());
```

(Though a `StringBuilder` may be overkill in this scenario)

Comment: xlsx.fileName has a space in it ("Journal 05032"). How can I use that as an argument in Process.Start()? First it tries to open Journal.xlsx, and then it tries 05032.xlsx

Comment: @Andrew - Wrap the whole thing in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You should open the file by calling `Process.Start(filename)`.
This will open the file in the user's default program, without tying your code to Excel.

If you need to manipulate Excel, that won't help.